# JQuery Mobile Internal and External Pages

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with JQM where an external page's working code inside an internal page would not load.

Here is the code for the external page (works fine on its own):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />

<link href="jquery.zrssfeed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>zRSSFeed - Basic RSS Feed Example</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>zRSSFeed - Basic RSS Feed Example</h1>
<p>Simple as it gets, this example uses the same code as in the documentation.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', {
        limit: 5
    });
});
</script>

<div id="test"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now...the problem is when I put that code into an internal page:

```
....<script src="jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> //include in head...


<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   


    <p>Page content goes here.</p>



             <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', {
                limit: 5
            });
        });
        </script>

<div id="test"></div>           

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Is there any extra requirments to get this to work?

For some reason the feed does not appear at all in the internal page.

Comment: Do you get any particular errors in your console?

Comment: No, it's just that the feed does not appear at all in the internal page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

When you are using AJAX to load the pages, then it seems like only referenced **pages** (`<div data-role="page"> ... </div>`) are loaded and not the complete website, this way the script doesn't get excuted.

You need to include your script to load in the **page-div** not in the head, to get the conde on page load.

#### Your start/landing page

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
    <!-- Loaded via AJAX because data-ajax="false" or rel="external" is not set -->
    <a href="page2.htm" data-role="button">To page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Page to load

```
<html>
    <!-- ... more html -->
    <script src="jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- ... more html -->

    <div data-role="page" id="rss_page">
        <!-- your stuff -->
    </div>
</html>
```

#### What gets loaded (via AJAX)

```
    <div data-role="page" id="rss_page">
        <!-- your stuff -->
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried adding the script inside the page div but the rss still doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to debug with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It is a Firefox extension.

1. Install Firebug from http://getfirebug.com/
2. Open your internal page and click **FireBug** icon in browse toolbar. You will see the panel at the bottom.
3. Click **Net** tab and refresh your page to check all required files are loaded. You will see the missing files in red color. Fix them.
4. **Console** tab to see Javascript error.

Hope you can find the solution.

Comment: If your page is uploaded to website, can you share the link?

Comment: Have you tried creating 2 internal pages and linking from internal page 1 to internal page 2 where internal page 2 will have the RSS Feed?

Comment: Yes. Correct. I have to use rel="external" in link. <a href="page1.html" rel="external">Page 1</a> <a href="page2.html" rel="external">Page 2</a>. It works.

Comment: It works for me too if I use external pages but I'm trying internal pages where links would be: <a href="#page2" /> ... this does'nt work for me

Comment: Feed will not display if page is loaded via Ajax. try data-ajax="false"

Comment: I've tried <a href="#page2" data-ajax="false" /> and and feed is still not appearing...does it actually work for you using internal links "#page2" ?